# How to set toolbar title and subtitle in centre

Tags: android

In my case I want to set toolbar title and subtitle in centre. I have already one solution to set **custom layout** in toolbar. Is that any other solution to set toolbar title and subtitle without using custom layout?

**Solution 1:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I don't want to use custom layout to set toolbar title and subtitle.I appreciate your effort, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">        
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i don't want to use custom layout.

Comment: do you want to use in the menu like items?

Comment: No, i have to display title and subtitle toolbar in centre and also i have many activity and fragment. so i'm not using custom layout.